# CRF model trained on plural, not working on singular

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, crf

I have made a CRF model. My data set has 24 classes and at this time I am in beginning so my training data has just 1200 tokens/corpus. I have train the model. In my training data I have used the plural of tokens like addresses, photos, states, countries etc.

Now at the time of testing if I give plural of tokens in sentence form to this model then it work good but if I enter my sentence in singular like photo, state etc then it does not assign any tag to it.

This behavior of crf is looking very strange. I have explore the [NER Feature Factory](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html) and used some lemma features but it also did not work. Sharing my `austen.prop` for the model formation.

```
# location of the training file
trainFile = training_data_for_ner.txt
# location where you would like to save (serialize) your
# classifier; adding .gz at the end automatically gzips the file,
# making it smaller, and faster to load
serializeTo = ner-model.ser.gz

# structure of your training file; this tells the classifier that
# the word is in column 0 and the correct answer is in column 1
map = word=0,answer=1,pos=2,lemma=3

# This specifies the order of the CRF: order 1 means that features
# apply at most to a class pair of previous class and current class
# or current class and next class.
maxLeft=1

# these are the features we'd like to train with
# some are discussed below, the rest can be
# understood by looking at NERFeatureFactory
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
# word character ngrams will be included up to length 6 as prefixes
# and suffixes only 
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useDisjunctive=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
# the last 4 properties deal with word shape features
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
# newly added features.
useLemmas=true
usePrevNextLemmas=true
useLemmaAsWord=true
useTags=true
```

Last four features were added by reading that `NER Feature Factory`. If anyone can help me to solve this problem then I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrain it with stemmed tokens. See https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/Stemmer.java (`main` method) for example.

Comment: And can I keep both lemma and stemmed token at a same time? Will it be okay for crf model formation?

Comment: That depends on your dataset. I'd guess that you should not do that. Note that you always can check the quality (F1 score or similar) with cross-validation, and choose most suitable options.

Comment: How will I specify to my map that this particular column contains stemmed token? Let say 5th column in training file contains stemmed token then how should I write my map in austen.prop. map = ...... stem = 4 or stemmer=4 ?

Comment: I think you should replace your `training_data_for_ner.txt` with stemmed words. Personally I have accessed StanfordNLP programmatically, and don't have much experience with `austen.prop`, sorry for that.